# F# Azure Web App deployment via Git Issue (Bitbucket)

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, f#, msbuild, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying an F# WebApi + MVC app to Azure via the Git (bitbucket) process and everything works fine until the final stage of the process. After a 'sync' or a commit the Azure tool blows up with the following error in the activity log:

error MSB4062: The "MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File" task could not be loaded from the assembly

Andy body experience and solve this?

Comment: Does it happen with a fresh new F# project or only with yours? That could help isolate a bit.

Comment: Not sure it's the same issue, but does this help? http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/08/26/running-a-pure-f-web-api-on-azure-web-sites

Comment: Hey guys,  Thanks for the suggestions - should have the result by tom.